# CRM For Outlook support for Synchronization of Appointments with POP3/SMTP Mailboxes

Tags: exchange-server, pop3, dynamics-crm-online

I wanted to know if and how CRM For Outlook application (for the Outlook client) carries out synchronization of Appointments, Tasks and Contacts with CRM Online. I am also not sure if POP3/SMTP supports Appointments, Contacts or Tasks of any kind.

I Googled for this information but was not able to find desired information.
Kindly advised.

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of ways to do this and there is documentation available, I suggest looking at the following:

[Integrate your email system with Microsoft Dynamics CRM](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn832099.aspx).

> To store email and other messaging records in CRM, you need to
>   synchronize your email system with CRM. There are three ways to do
>   this:
>
> - Server-side synchronization
> - Microsoft Dynamics CRM for Outlook
> - Microsoft Dynamics CRM Email Router
>
> You can also use server-side synchronization together with Dynamics
>   CRM for Outlook.

[Outlook Synchronization in Microsoft Dynamics CRM](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48718)

> **Overview of CRM for Outlook synchronization**
>
> Microsoft Dynamics CRM manages replication of information between the
>   central CRM database and the local data store on a computer running
>   Microsoft Dynamics CRM for Microsoft Outlook by using Outlook
>   synchronization and server-side synchronization.
>
> **Outlook synchronization**
>
> CRM for Outlook (also known as “the Outlook client”) supports Outlook
>   synchronization, which is synchronizing CRM contacts and CRM
>   activities to Outlook folders. Outlook synchronization enables Outlook
>   users to view CRM information, including contacts, tasks, phone calls,
>   letters, faxes, appointments, and email, within the Outlook interface.
>
> **Server-side synchronization**
>
> Starting with Dynamics CRM 2013, server-side synchronization is
>   available, which is used to integrate CRM with Exchange and POP3 or
>   SMTP-based email servers. This has benefits compared to using the
>   email router because it’s built in to CRM and doesn’t require a
>   separate component. It also has benefits compared to Outlook
>   synchronization by eliminating the load on clients.